# PHP How to INSERT to Table Many Times in Once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a logical problem with my database, let me explain. There is my system:

- I have users and admins.
- Admins can create project and if they needed they can add the related users on the project.
- 1 user can work many projects and 1 project can have many users.(many to many)

I build relational database and it works fine. But the problem is, which users are working on which project(s) ? I don't know how to INSERT them to database. Admins can choose the users from the list and then the selected users should stored with the dependent project. But I couldn't managed to INSERT it to database. Here my tables and some codes.

```
--projects--      --users--        --projectUsers--
userId            userId           userId  
creationDate      registerDate     projectId
projectId         email
title             permission
priority          name
content           surname
endDate           birthDate
                  password

$sql="INSERT INTO projects (
        projectId, 
        userId, 
        creationDate, 
        title,
        priority,
        content,
        endDate     
        )VALUES(
        '$projectId', 
        '$userId', 
        '$creationDate', 
        '$title',
        '$priority',
        '$content',
        '$endDate'
        )";

        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


        $sql2="INSERT INTO projectUsers (
        projectId, 
        userId  
        )VALUES(
        '$projectId', 
        '$userId'
        )";

        $result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
```

The table "projectUsers" stores 2 foreign keys. When the admin creates a project, his userId and the new projectId stores on the "projectUsers" and also stores on the "projects" table. But admin will choose the which users will depended with this project, and he can choose more then one in once. How should I INSERT the dependent users on the data base. And also I don't want to store more then 1 user in a row. And I should able to get answer this queries:

1. which users are working on which project(s) ?
2. which users are working on this project ?
3. This user working on which(s) project ?

Example: Admin creates a new project and select 3 dependent users. I want to insert them the table "projectUsers".When admin creates the project, I want to see my "projectUser" table like this:

```
userId    projectId
1          1
2          1
3          1
```

P.S: The "userId" on the "projects" table shows me the who created this project. Like an owner.

Comment: Remove the `userId` from your projects table. From there on, all your queries are just basic three table joins.

Comment: Something strange you have. Remove `user_id` from `projects`, since you will be using a separate *link* table `projectUsers`

Comment: Is the user_id in your project table the user who created it or the owner or something other than a general user?  If so then rename it to something like CreateUserId or OwnerUserId - this then shows this is still a UserId from the User table, but it has special meaning, other than just a general participant.

Comment: What error/problem do you encounter when trying to enter values into the projectUsers table? What is the field definition for the projectUsers table - specifically asking if the userId and projectId are set up as autoincremenet fields? OR the primary key on the projectUsers table has to include both fields - it cannot have just projectId or userId as both will be duplicated.  Clutching at straws  without the error messages.

Comment: There is no any error, just I need a php command or need to change table to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `userId` from your projects table, you're storing that information in the `ProjectUsers` association table anyway. For every user working on a project, you have to create a separate row in the `ProjectUsers` table.

From there on, all your retrieval queries are just basic three table joins:

**1. Which users are working on which project(s)?**

```
SELECT * FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN ProjectUsers pu
    ON p.projectId = pu.projectId
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON pu.userId = u.userId
```

**2. Which users are working on this project?**

```
SELECT * FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN ProjectUsers pu
    ON p.projectId = 123 AND p.projectId = pu.projectId
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON pu.userId = u.userId
```

**3. This user is working on which projects?**

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN ProjectUsers pu
    ON u.userId = 123 AND u.userId = pu.userId
LEFT JOIN Projects p
    ON pu.projectId = p.projectId
```

Comment: But I can't INSERT selected users in once, I want to insert them the table "projectUsers". Lets say admin creating a project and he is selecting 3 dependent users. When admin creates the project, I want to see my "projectUser" table like this:

userId    projectId

1          1
2          1
3          1

Comment: Right, so what stops you from doing that? Just execute three `INSERT` statements on `ProjectUsers`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I mean I need to create a new row on the tabs for each dependent user.

Answer (score 0):

The Projects and Users need to be created first for the foreign key, then simply 1, 2 & 3. Add each user for each project that is selected.

```
INSERT INTO ProjectUsers (userId, projectId) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO ProjectUsers (userId, projectId) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO ProjectUsers (userId, projectId) VALUES (3, 1);
```

Other than this we are really struggling to understand the context of your problem.  You've tagged the problem as SQL, but you have the query to do the INSERT correct.  What we don't have is a full definition of the table - if that is raising errors.

If you're problem is is within the PHP, then you've got too many SQL tags, because that is what people are trying to solve.

Please, Please, Please change the UserId in Projects to be OwnerUserId - the description about what this data field represents is as important as indicating what table it joins to, so concatenating these together gives full meaning to the field, and removes ambiguity.

Comment: What if the admin wants the add 4 maybe 6, 10 is allright to, what if admin adds only 1 or nothing. Its not a solution.

Comment: @ArdaÖzceviz Do you really have trouble seeing this. If you want to add 4, then you run the query in your question 4 times. If they want to add 10, then run it 10 times and replace the userId for each time you run it.  Your problem is not is SQL - because you have the answer for that in your question - $sql2 contains the code I have listed, it is the same thing just with the values include in place of the variable.